# Redirect Addresses to localhost by Pattern on Mac OS X

Tags: apache-2.2, mac-osx, localhost, virtualhost, hosts

I'm not even 100% sure how to ask this question. The answer might be out there, but I can't find it.

So I've set up virtual hosts for my Mac and I do all my development locally on my computer. I have a `vhost` folder in my `Sites` folder, and I have a list of folders, such as:

```
recipes.cam
database.cam
sandbox.cam
codeigniter.cam
```

and in my `/etc/hosts` file I have an entry for each one:

```
# vhosts
127.0.0.1 recipes.cam
127.0.0.1 database.cam
127.0.0.1 sandbox.cam
127.0.0.1 codeigniter.cam
# ...
```

And this works great. When I go to http://recipes.cam in my browser, it shows the contents of the `~/Sites/vhosts/recipes.cam/`.

**So this is my question**: Is there a way to have any address that end in `.cam` to redirect to localhost? So I don't have to create a new entry in `hosts` every time I add a new directory (it happens pretty often).

I tried `127.0.0.1 *.cam` in my `hosts` file, but it didn't work :-/

Answer (score 1):

You could install a local DNS server/resolver (e.g. BIND) with a `.cam` zone containing a wildcard entry and have your resolv.conf point to localhost. The other requests you can either forward to your normal DNS resolver, or resolve them using the root servers.

Comment: Is there a Mac version of this sort of software? Any good tutorials on how to set it up?

Comment: BIND is portable, I don't think it is a problem getting it to work on MacOS. But I'm no mac user, so I cannot really help you with that. Google for something like "Install BIND on MacOS".